# Display advanced custom field (ACF) value from custom post type taxonomy - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, taxonomy

In Wordpress I created a custom post type called "Sports" with a taxonomy called "sport_locations". Using the advanced custom field (ACF) plugin I created fields to show on taxonomy terms. I got everything to work, however I'm having trouble outputting the image I uploaded.

In ACF I have the option for the return value of the image to be: an object, url, or ID. Right now I have it set to object.

Below is the code I have so far. I'm writing this code inside of the single-sports.php . I created a foreach loop and only spitting out the terms associated to that specific sport.

When I do the var_dump I keep getting bool(false). Sorry for the extra commenting out in the code I was trying a bunch of different things and figured I'd leave it in my code as reference

post type = sports

taxonomy = sport_location

acf field = location_image (return value = object)

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'sport_locations' );
    //$LocImg = $wp_query->queried_object;


    // echo '<pre>';
    // echo var_dump($LocImg);
    // echo '</pre>';

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    $term_thumb = get_field('location_image', 'sport_locations'.$term->term_id);

    echo '<pre>'; 
    echo var_dump($term_thumb);
    echo '</pre>';


        echo '<div class="sport-single">';

                echo'<img src="' .$term_thumb['url']. '" class="img-responsive">';
                //echo '<img src="' .$locationImage[0]. '" class="placeholder" />';
                //echo '<img src="' .get_src_picture(get_field("location_image", "sport_locations".$LocImg->term_id), "category"). '" class="img-responsive" />';
                //echo '<img src="' .get_field( "location_image", $LocImg->taxonomy . "_" . $LocImg->term_id ). '" />';
                echo '<p><a href="/sport_location/'.$term->slug .'/">'.$term->name .'</a></p>';

        echo '</div>';

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is supposed to be an underscore between the term name and the ID. So...

```
$term_thumb = get_field('location_image', 'sport_locations'.$term->term_id);
```

...should be...

```
$term_thumb = get_field('location_image', 'sport_locations_'.$term->term_id);
```

Alternatively, you can pass the term object...

```
$term_thumb = get_field('location_image', $term);
```

Comment: I'm still getting a bool(false) and when i inspect element inside of my img src im getting <img src="(unknown)'

Comment: got it I had to add this : $url = $image['url'];